# Oracle SQL Fast Retrieval of a Negative condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Not sure if I am asking the question correctly

I have a table with 2K records. Each record represents a huge Batch processing Unit and it is marked with an initial status of 0(Zero).  Every time the batch is completed, the status is updated for that Batch record=10. This Marks that row/Batch  as completed

What is the fastest way to see if All records have the status as 10.  The query can return true or false or count as soon as it encounters the first 0(Zero). Only in the worst-case scenario, it has to go thru the entire table and return.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest would probably be:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from t where status <> 10)
             then 'incomplete' else 'complete'
        end)
from dual;
```

This can use an index on `(status)`, which should make the lookup even faster.

However, I would recommend changing the "batch job" to write a message when it is complete -- such as updating a "completed time" column in a `batches` table.  Why query for completeness when the batch knows if it is done?

Comment: One Job has multiple Batches. So this table stores the status of each batch. There is another table that stores the Job status. So when all the batches are complete, then the job will be marked as complete

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
select null as col
from   your_table
where  status = 0  AND ROWNUM = 1
;
```

(or `select` whatever you want from the first row encountered that has `status = 0`; the way I wrote the query, it will only tell you if there are incomplete batches, but it won't tell you anything else.)

The `ROWNUM` condition forces execution to stop as soon as the first `status = 0` is encountered - either from the table itself, or from an index if you have an index on the `status` column (as you might, if this kind of query is common in your business).

The query will return either a single row - with `NULL` in the only column `col`, unless you choose to select something from the record - or **no rows** if all batches are complete.